# Anniversary Game Jam 2014

Tags: discussion, gamejam

## Congratulations, everyone!

The jam has ended, and the voting has started already. Check out the answers to this question and the games inside them, and vote them up if you think they deserve it. Downvotes are fine if that's how you want to vote, but at least leave a comment so the creators know how they should improve.

The voting will end on [Sunday, November 9th, at 00:00 UTC](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=GDSE+Fall+Game+Jam+2014+Voting+Closes&iso=20141109T00&p1=1440) (7 days after the end of the competition, minus a few hours so that I can be awake to close it) If you wanted to participate but didn't have the chance, don't be sad! There will be another jam in the Winter!

Original text:

> ## Time
>
> The Anniversary Game Jam 2014 will officially take place between
>   [October 31st
>   5am](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=GDSE+Fall+Game+Jam+2014&iso=20141031T05&p1=1440)
>   and [November 3rd
>   7am](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?msg=GDSE+Fall+Game+Jam+2014&iso=20141103T07&p1=1440)
>   UTC. Effectively Friday evening through to Sunday night for your time
>   zone.
>
> Please submit your game before Sunday late-night for your time zone as
>   you will not have time to work on your game on Monday.
>
> ## Rules
>
> We're going to keep the same rules as before:
>
> - Participants are allowed to write games for any platform.
> - All publicly available libraries and middleware are allowed. All publicly available creation tools (e.g. Photoshop or 3DS Max) are
>     allowed.
> - The entrant is allowed use any premade assets as long as they're freely available on the web before the start of the jam, and the
>     licenses allow them to be used in an open source project (e.g.
>     opengameart.org). If you plan to use assets you've created prior to
>     the jam, release them to opengameart or the like before the jam
>     begins.
> - Assets created by the entrant during the game jam may also be used.
> - The forming of teams is not allowed.
> - Each entrant may ask questions on the main gamedev.stackexchange site, as long as the questions are on-topic as per normal site rules.
>     Alternatively, the
>     [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development)
>     may also be used.
> - Each entrant must release their game as open source after attaching a license of their choice.
>
> ## Theme
>
> Potluck Jam! Before the jam, everyone submitted 5 words into the
>   potluck. When the jam started, each participant was assigned 5 random
>   words from those submitted. Contestants pick 3 of these words to use
>   as their personal theme. If you are late to the game, come over to
>   [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development), and
>   we can hook you up. Here are the word assignments:
>
> - [**afunplatypus**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/54443/afunplatypus):
>     Force, Redirection, Following, Underground, Explosions
> - [**ali-s**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/7328/ali-s): Concurrency, Laser, Delusion, Airlifter, Attack
> - <strike>[**almo**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/12670/almo):
>     Experimental, Acid, Mace, Armory, Energy-shield</strike>
> - [**anko**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/7804/anko): Explosions, HYPER-challenging, Heights, Automation, Destroy
> - [**ashes999**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/1929/ashes999):
>     Spy, Flat, Bread, Lasers, Dream
> - [**attackinghobo**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/962/attackinghobo):
>     Water, Skis, Spider, Latvian, Dodging
> - [**bbdude95**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/36734/bbdude95):
>     Mana, Turtle, Sisyphus, City, Pacifism
> - <strike>[**byte56**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/7191/byte56):
>     Industry, Bum, Parallelism, Heaven, Hat</strike>
> - [**congusbongus**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/26250/congusbongus):
>     Earth, Existential, Honey, Empire, Crossbow
> - [**costava**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/49041/costava):
>     Space, Floating, Piece, Flogging, Ocean
> - [**cyborg**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/51699/cyborg): Mustard, Pancakes, Warp, Fruit-tree, Detective
> - [**delkaan**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/54474/delkaan): Panda, Imagination, Blue, Timetravel, Explosion
> - [**joe**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/40623/joe): Matter, Flat, Backtrack, Light, Population
> - [**john-mcdonald**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/9366/john-mcdonald):
>     Wind, Power, BBQ, Gear, Cows
> - [**lasse**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/32955/lasse): Evolution, Vortex, Non-combat, Roomba, Upgrade
> - [**lokkij**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/31464/lokkij): Harvest, Fluidic, Square, Elevator, Paranoia
> - [**micklh**](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/87783/micklh): Experimental, Acid, Mace, Armory, Energy-shield
> - [**mlm**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/16587/mlm): Meats, Lasers, Deep, Blink, Void
> - [**paraknight**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/36097/paraknight):
>     Meta, Wormhole, Tactical, Unity, Bears
> - [**pip**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/30021/pip): Generator, Cespool, Marble, Boxes, Future
> - [**spartandonut**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/13052/spartandonut):
>     Ninja, Battlefield, Bouncy, Panic, Crafting
> - [**the-phantom-derpstorm**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/40253/the-phantom-derpstorm):
>     Romance, Polka, Work, Detcord, Caves
> - [**trilarion**](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/users/46410/trilarion): Fast, Fire, Interruption, Defend, Robots
>
> ## All Done?
>
> When your game is complete, add an answer here with a link to a
>   playable version, a link to the source, a screenshot or two, and what
>   your 5 words were. Don't forget to vote on the other games, and have
>   fun!
>
> Please refrain from voting on your favorites until the jam has
>   concluded. You will have an entire week to vote on the games at the
>   conclusion of the jam.

Comment: let the brainstorming begin!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't participate, I just wanted to bring some food to the potluck, not eat. Though, "Bum Hat Heaven" would have been a fun game.

Comment: Closed to prevent new submissions during the voting period.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Panda Replay

[image: Panda Replay]

In this puzzle / platformer game, you control a panda. The goal is to collect the yellow token to advance to the next stage. The panda can push the light brown crates and bombs, but can not be blown up by the bomb. The panda has the ability to "time travel". Time travelling allows the panda to maintain his current position on the map while "resetting" the puzzle to what it was in the beginning, allowing him to perform actions that were previously not possible. He can only time travel a limited number of times per stage.

- Given words: **Panda, Imagination, Blue, Timetravel, Explosion**
- Used words: **Panda, Explosion, Timetravel**

[**Play the game**](http://kendaldev.com/PandaReplay/) / [**Code**](https://github.com/delkaan/panda-replay)

**Note:** It might take a while to load. If you get a black screen, it's loading. Also, some people have had problems on Firefox. If you do, try it on Chrome.

### Controls

Use the arrow keys to move the panda. Spacebar or the up key to jump. Use "T" to time travel. Icons on the top right of the screen allow you to jump between completed puzzles and reload the current puzzle.

### Technology

Phaser, Tiled

Comment: Great job! Loved the puzzles you were able to produce with the gameplay mechanic. FYI: I had a weird issue where level 2 was impossible because my panda was slow. I switched from FF to Chrome, and the panda was much more responsive.

Answer (score 10):

## Bohr automaton

Theme-words: **Heights**, **Automation**, **Destroy**

[image: screenshot]

It's a web-based puzzle game; inspired by [Niels Bohr](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niels_Bohr)'s electron [energy level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Energy_level) theory.

#### [Play it](http://cyan.io/bohr-automaton/) | [Browse code](https://github.com/anko/Bohr-Automaton)

<sup>(Works best in Chrome/Chromium on desktop. Others likely have rendering bugs.)</sup>

### How to play

**Aim**: Destroy red anti-electrons around your atom, by touching them with electrons.

**Controls**: Arrange the green electrons on orbits with drag-and-drop, then click the nucleus (center circle) to set them off moving automatically. Click on the nucleus again to reset. To skip between levels, click the little level indicators around the nucleus.

**Rules**: (The levels are tutorial-like, so maybe just play it.) Electrons move clockwise along their orbits. Each has a "spin" (direction indicated by icon), which determines whether it stays at the same orbit height (square), rises by one every step (up arrow) or drops by one every step (down arrow). Electrons disappear if they go above the highest orbit or lower than the lowest. When an electron destroys an anti-electron, it absorbs its spin and starts moving in that way.

### Tech overview

Written in [LiveScript](http://livescript.net/), rendered in [SVG](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalable_Vector_Graphics) with [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). Sounds in [Bfxr](http://www.bfxr.net/) and [SunVox](http://www.warmplace.ru/soft/sunvox/).

More details and build instructions in [the `README.md`](https://github.com/anko/Bohr-Automaton).

Answer (score 5):

### Cow War

[**Play Now!**](http://cow-war.jcpmcdonald.com/) | [Browse Source](https://bitbucket.org/jcpmcdonald/cow-war/overview)

[image: Cow War]

- **5 Words:** Wind, Power, BBQ, Gear, Cows
- **Selected Words:** Wind, Power, Cows

COW POWER! Make your cows work for you by sending them to the mill where they will increase your cow power. The more cow power you have, the more Cattleium your farm will have. Spend Cattleium on more cows! Alternatively, send your cows to war! The first side to successfully hit the opponent's barn 5 times wins.

Controls: `Click and drag` \ `A` \ `D` \ `LEFT` \ `RIGHT` to look around. Click the giant buttons in the top center to do stuff.

Cows cost 10 Cattleium each. You start with 10 cow power (generated by the wind), and each cow increases your cow power by 1, who figured?

All assets were made myself. Thank goodness I found a decent cow to trace.

Moo

Comment: I just wanted to come and say Moo!

Comment: I played and got 137 cattleium when I played it days ago. I just tried playing today and none of the UI is showing up :/

Comment: @MLM, That is really strange, nothing has changed. Try refreshing.

Comment: @MLM, I tried it out and was able to reproduce the issue. I suspect that the recent Unity update from Beta 20 to RC1 caused an update in the players and broke my UI. I have installed RC1, recompiled, and re-uploaded. Everything should be like it was.

Answer (score 5):

## Traces

### [Play Now! *(online)*](https://madlittlemods.github.io/Traces/dist/)

[image]

- **5 Words:** Meats, Lasers, Deep, Blink, Void
- **Selected Words:** Meats, Lasers, Blink

Traces is twin stick shooter *(currently only mouse and keyboard)* with a pseudo-3D aesthetic. The goal is to power each building with the laser beam in sequential order all while killing or avoiding the enemy blobs. Activate the first building in sight and find the next building at the end of laser beam. Eat meat to restore your health.

### [GitHub *(source)*](https://github.com/MadLittleMods/Traces)

Answer (score 4):

## Homebound

Guide your crew home by programming your spaceship to reach that distant wormhole. Don't get too close to the planets or their gravity will crash you. Try to win with the fastest time, shortest script, lowest fuel expenditure, or most acrobatically awesome gravity assist! Gameplay is self-explanatory.

### [Play (Web)](https://db.tt/MNT7l8gx)

View the source code from directly in your browser; it's all just raw, unobfuscated JavaScript with 0 libraries!

[image: Screenshot]

My themes were: Meta, Wormhole, Tactical, Unity, Bears. Try to guess which ones I picked!

I wrote this in a hurry (single digit hours) because of a busy weekend, and you can tell by playing and looking at the code just how rough around the edges this game is, so I'll definitely be taking this further after the jam!

P.S. If a level seems impossible, refresh to regenerate from a new seed.

Answer (score 4):

## Time for pancakes!

[image]

- Given words: Mustard, Pancakes, Warp, Fruit-tree, Detective
- Used words: Pancakes, Fruit-tree, Warp

You have 2 minutes and 30 seconds to grab fruit from a stubborn tree that decides himself when to drop his fruit while managing 6 pancakes at once. Good luck! I also did something with the last used word, but you'll have to play to find out...

### Technology

Unity 3D 4.6

### Builds and Source Code

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a9xtsj6jxktuna0/AACcNnI-irSd1GXEeoVxjixha?dl=0)

Comment: The URL you pasted is linking to your private files. You need to paste in the public URL

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 3):

## [Diamond in the Rough](https://costava.github.io/Diamond-in-the-Rough/)

A lone ship defending the planets.

## [Play Online](https://costava.github.io/Diamond-in-the-Rough/)

#### For best results, download the entire [src folder from Github](https://github.com/Costava/Diamond-in-the-Rough/archive/master.zip), unzip it, and open index.html.

[image: Diamond in the Rough]

**My Five Words:** Space, Floating, Piece, Flogging, Ocean

Don't forget to brag about your score in the comments!

Known Issues:

- Sounds may be absent or delayed in Chrome (if you hear some sounds, it does not necessarily mean that you are hearing all of them)

  - The game works perfectly fine if you [download the src folder](https://github.com/Costava/Diamond-in-the-Rough/archive/master.zip), unzip it, and open index.html in Chrome. The sound issues in Chrome are ONLY when it is hosted online.
- May not load if open in multiple tabs

### [Source on Github](https://github.com/Costava/Diamond-in-the-Rough)

Comment: The `.zip` is biiiiig: 37MiB compressed, 44M expanded. The culprit [seems to be](http://i.imgur.com/u2NNa0D.png) `audio/Dream_2_Ambiance.wav`, weighing 22M. That might be the source of your sound issues. (I got score 42!)

Comment: Gah. I can only get to 26.

Comment: You should include credits for your assets, since some of them would be under CC-BY.

Comment: @congusbongus You are completely right. I added a section in the readme and an attribution file. I knew I needed to give credit and should have done it ASAP.